# Adding a single legend with very long text to a ggplot2 facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, facet-grid

Using R ggplot2 library, I an generating a facet_grid plot and I want to put a legend off to the right hand side of all the plots -NOT EACH INDIVIDUAL PLOT, but one legend that works for all the plots

```
g = ggplot(pd2, aes(x = p/1000, y=c/1000 )) + 
  geom_point(alpha=.1, colour="red") + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
  xlab("Ave P") +
  ylab("Ave C)") +
  labs(title = "Comparison ") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold",
           size=14, colour="black", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size=12, colour="blue")) +
  facet_grid(code ~ TheState) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(colour = "purple", angle = 0, 
        size = 9, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5))
```

What I want to do is have a legend off to the right that is turned 90 degrees - because I want the legend to refer to very_long_code instead of just "code."  I've tried all kinds of variations of legend, theme, and guide.  Intuitively, I would like to say,

```
legend(text, angle=90, very_long_code, color="purple")
```

The next step would be to not use a single color, but to use a different color for each one that would correspond to colors in the strip.

Comment: what is this `pd2` you are referring to?

Comment: pd2 is the dataframe containing columns:
code  p  c  TheState  very_long_code

Comment: Can you provide `dput(pd2)`?